# E/dalvikvm: Could not find class

Tags: android, logcat

I am experiencing a lock-up in my Android app when I touch an Action Bar button. I don't even get an ANR dialogue.

The only LogCat errors I am seeing are:

```
02-01 14:59:15.328 30107-30170/com.complync.complyncmobile E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.util.ArrayMap', referenced from method com.android.tools.fd.runtime.Restarter.getActivities
02-01 14:59:27.241 6513-6513/com.complync.complyncmobile E/Trace: error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
02-01 14:59:29.563 6513-6513/com.complync.complyncmobile E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.Application$OnProvideAssistDataListener', referenced from method com.complync.complyncmobile.Happlication.access$super
02-01 14:59:29.563 6513-6513/com.complync.complyncmobile E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.Application$OnProvideAssistDataListener', referenced from method com.complync.complyncmobile.Happlication.access$super
02-01 14:59:29.603 6513-6513/com.complync.complyncmobile E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.util.ArrayMap', referenced from method com.android.tools.fd.runtime.MonkeyPatcher.monkeyPatchExistingResources
02-01 14:59:29.923 6513-6513/com.complync.complyncmobile E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.View$OnApplyWindowInsetsListener', referenced from method com.complync.complyncmobile.compoundcontrols.NumericKeypad.access$super
02-01 14:59:29.934 6513-6513/com.complync.complyncmobile E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.WindowInsets', referenced from method com.complync.complyncmobile.compoundcontrols.NumericKeypad.access$super
02-01 14:59:29.954 6513-6513/com.complync.complyncmobile E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.WindowInsets', referenced from method com.complync.complyncmobile.compoundcontrols.NumericKeypad.access$super
02-01 15:00:18.215 6513-6633/com.complync.complyncmobile E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'java.beans.Transient', referenced from method com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.JacksonAnnotationIntrospector$Java7Support.<init>
02-01 15:00:18.225 6513-6633/com.complync.complyncmobile E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'java.beans.ConstructorProperties', referenced from method com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.JacksonAnnotationIntrospector$Java7Support.findConstructorName
02-01 15:00:18.225 6513-6633/com.complync.complyncmobile E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'java.beans.Transient', referenced from method com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.JacksonAnnotationIntrospector$Java7Support.findTransient
02-01 15:00:18.225 6513-6633/com.complync.complyncmobile E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'java.beans.ConstructorProperties', referenced from method com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.JacksonAnnotationIntrospector$Java7Support.hasCreatorAnnotation
```

I am struggling to understand the origin of these errors.

Comment: can you post some code

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, application is not crashing but log cat shows bunch of errors.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. did anyone found the root problem?

Answer (score 4):

The logs that you're getting are normal. They simply represent those classes that are referred from your code conditionally. So, it doesn't matter if they exist or not.

The mentioned classes are not found because they don't exist on your device or the emulator at which you're running the app.

Why don't they exist? Because they were introduced in newer Android versions.

Pickup your first class from the log for example:

> Could not find class 'android.util.ArrayMap'

ArrayMap was introduced in [API level 19](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/ArrayMap.html), probably you're running your app on an older version, and that's why the error is logged. They are harmless however.